# unable to access model related with has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relational-database, has-one

I have two models: `Show` and `Venue`. Show has one venue while each venue belongs to show. This condition is defined in both model files with `has_one` & `belongs_to` statements properly. However, I'm not able to access the venue by doing `show.venue`. Consider the following code where s is a `Show` instance:

```
logger.info("*********************")
logger.info("#{s.inspect}")
logger.info("#{Venue.find(s.venue_id)}") # Works
logger.info("#{s.venue}") # Causes a MySQL Error
logger.info("*********************")
```

I feel like the line that causes the MySQL error should work. This is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'venues.show_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `venues` WHERE (`venues`.show_id = 95)  LIMIT 1)
```

I have no idea why it is trying to access `venues.show_id`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the foreign keys reversed.  In ActiveRecord's conventions, the class with the belongs_to should map to the database table with the foreign key.  See the [ActiveRecord API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html): "The belongs_to association is always used in the model that has the foreign key."  This makes some sense, if you think about the way that belongs_to interacts with both has_one and has_many (as you obviously can't put the foreign keys in the has_many model).

Comment: i guess i got a bit confused because i think like this:
"If a show HAS a venue, then a show HAS a venue_id to reference that venue." But I have to start thinking "If a show BELONGS to a venue, it must the id of the venue it BELONGS to."